# Port Forwarded; Port Check says port is open but unable to connect

Tags: port, portforwarding

I have setup the Swann DVR Surveillance System. I am able to access the web client at 192.168.1.99:85 (static ip in internal LAN). I have port forwarded 85 packets to 192.168.1.99. But when I access my external ip eg xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:85 I get unable to connect error.

I checked if the port is open in an online tool and it says port 85 is open. HEre is my port forwarding page:

[image]

Please Help me. Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have tried changing ports to 89, 9001, 8080 and no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive finally figured out what I was doing wrong from a friend. It seems there is something called NAT Loopback (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) that allows you to access your public IP address from within your own network. Most routers have this feature disabled by default. And hence whenever you try to access your IP address the packets are dropped and you get the Host Unreachable ICMP packet.

Anyway to use this try to enable NAT Reflection or NAT Loopback on your router.

If you dont have that feature, you can test your system from outside the network and itll work just fine. Sorry for not reporting the answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, same problem.  As Steve Robinson said, you cannot always access your public IP from your NAT.  Try running Apache and use your phone (turn off WiFi and turn on mobile data) to test if this is the case.